# Can I achieve DBMS_Application, DBMS_Session, DBMS_Output in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for alternatives in SQL Server for the below three functions which are currently performed using Oracle.

These are the Oracle features we need to use in SQL Server basically:

1. `DBMS_Application` (Tracing option in Oracle).
2. `DBMS_Session` (Used in Oracle).
3. Disable or enable `DBMS_Output` at database level.

We are moving from Oracle to SQL Server and we want to ensure the functionality equivalents are available and ready to use so I can start testing.

What would be the SQL Server functionality equivalent of these features we use with Oracle?

Comment: one of project requirement was they want to move from Oracle to SQL server how ever they want same functionality so i am trying to get some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO

**Note:** *You should test and pick which works best or which combinations of these work best for your needs. Test thoroughly and compare results while ensuring none of these cause overhead issues with the SQL Server instance. For example SQL Profiler is resource intense so use caution.*

Based on the general description of the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` package functionality per the Oracle docs, a few things with SQL Server will provide equivalent functionality. I'll list a few below for you to dig into with more detail and for a starting point, etc.

- > [**DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB)
  >
  > Application developers can use the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` package with
  >   Oracle Trace and the SQL trace facility to record names of executing
  >   modules or transactions in the database for later use when tracking
  >   the performance of various modules and debugging.
  >
  > [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB)

**The SQL Server `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` equivelants. . .**

- [SQL Server Profiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Extended Events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SQL Server Audit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)
- [System Dynamic Management Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/)

  - [Automate capturing SQL Server activity with `SP_WHOISACTIVE` and `SP_WHO2` via a SQL Agent job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161752/automated-sp-whoisactive-sql-activity-capturing-issue/161830#161830)

---

### DBMS_SESSION

Based on the general description of the `DBMS_SESSION` package functionality per the Oracle docs, use [`ALTER EVENT SESSION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`ALTER ROLE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`sp_addrolemember`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for providing equivalent functionality with SQL Server.

- > [**DBMS_SESSION**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS054)
  >
  > This package provides access to SQL `ALTER SESSION` and `SET ROLE`
  >   statements, and other session information, from PL/SQL. You can use
  >   `DBMS_SESSION` to set preferences and security levels.
  >
  > [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS054)

---

### DBMS_OUTPUT

Based on the general description of the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package functionality per the Oracle docs, you can just use [`PRINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`SELECT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to output the message and write the logic accordingly. Without getting into all the detail of the [`DBMS_OUTPUT Subprograms`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67314) one by one, it seems that's the general and basic functionality it provides is controlling output and debug output of stored procedures and such.

- > [**DBMS_OUTPUT**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm)
  >
  > The `DBMS_OUTPUT` package enables you to send messages from stored
  >   procedures, packages, and triggers. The package is especially useful
  >   for displaying PL/SQL debugging information

Additionally and for example, according to a response on the ["How to Print the Value of a Variable in SQL Server"](https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-can-i-print-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-server-032110) post it is stated and sounds right to me too based on my past MSSQL usage. . .

- > I don't think there is a straight up SQL equivalent. I don't know of
  >   any direct capabilities for leaving a list for a trigger or another
  >   routine. Usually, I would just use a #temp table or function
  >   parameters to pass intermediate results.
  >
  > If you want to see intermediate results for edit purposes, the PRINT
  >   function works - e.g. in a stored procedure, it's a common debugging
  >   routine to insert print statements to show intermediate results in the
  >   edit environment.
  >
  > [Source](https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-can-i-print-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-server-032110)

---

### Further Resources

- [Serveroutput from a TSQL procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866602/serveroutput-from-a-tsql-procedure)

Comment: Thanks Pimp , I will follow the above instruction and get back to you.

Comment: I have share the same to my team and we have not done complete testing on this

Comment: but your suggestions had help me lot to move further